# How to get notification on successfull JMS Connection

Tags: java, spring-jms

I am using spring DefaultMessageListenerContainer and SingleConnectionFactory to connect to WMQ queue.
I want my application to send me a mail when it successfully connects to WMQ queue.

In case of server failover it will retry untill connection is successful, I want a mail after retry is successful.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a wrapper `ConnectionFactory` that delegates its method calls to the real connection factory.

You can then put your email logic (perhaps using a [Spring Integration Mail Sending Channel Adapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mail.html#mail-outbound) in the `createConnection()` method.